# How to work wirth WCF services in ASP.Net Boilerplate?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, aspnetboilerplate, asp.net-boilerplate

I want to do CRUD by web-services(WCF), but i am using boilerplate framework , my question is how to work with web-services(WCF) in boilerplate?? any helpful link or tutorial??

Comment: can you explain more? are you trying to host wcf or consuming wcf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new project in your solution with WCF application, add wcf service in this new project, use entity framework and then write services you need, then in YourProject.Web project add service reference and get the service you need. Create object of the service in your controller and get or post data according to your need. Set multiple startup projects from solution properties and give WcfService-Project and Yorproject.web-Project as start. Now start both projects and use services. That's all.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Got it